# MySQL WHERE clause in SELECT query not behaving as intended

Tags: mysql

This is *definitely* user error - there's nothing wrong with the underlying data or MySQL.

What I'm trying to do within the WHERE clause is SELECT all material_batch_id's and the SUM'd quantity from within said batches (contained within material_batch_track) where there is currently NO corresponding entry in stocktakes_items **or**, there **are** one or more entries in stocktakes_items for the given material_batch_id BUT it has been checked and already counted as 0 and thus doesn't need to be checked again.

Despite wearing out 3 desks hitting my head against them, the query is still not quite doing what I need and I'm reasonably confident that the issue lies around the structure of the latter part of my WHERE clause.

**I haven't included all the underlying data structures as I am 99% confident this is a query structure issue, but if someone thinks that's not the case do let me know and I will update my question.**

Is there a genius in the house who can see where I'm going wrong please??

```
SELECT mb.material_batch_id AS mbid, SUM( mbt.qty ) AS expected_qty
FROM materials_batch AS mb
LEFT JOIN materials_batch_track mbt ON mbt.mbid = mb.material_batch_id
LEFT JOIN stocktakes_items sti ON sti.mbid = mb.material_batch_id
LEFT JOIN stocktakes st ON st.stid = sti.stid
  WHERE mb.material_id =2
    AND mb.batch_status
    IN (
      'Arrived',  'Completed'
    )
    AND mb.batch_type = 'whole'
    AND sti_id IS NULL 
    OR (
      qty_recorded !=0
      AND qty_expected !=0
    )
    AND st.status NOT 
    IN (
      'Cancelled',  'In Progress'
    )
GROUP BY mbid
```

The query simply returns no results, which isn't correct. I'm thinking there is an issue around the area of ... '`AND sti_id IS NULL OR ( )`'

The table structure of the (in my mind) problem area is:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM stocktakes_items;
+--------+------+------+--------------+--------------+
| sti_id | stid | mbid | qty_expected | qty_recorded |
+--------+------+------+--------------+--------------+
|      1 |    1 |    1 |            0 |            0 |
|      2 |    1 |    3 |            1 |            0 |
|      3 |    1 |    9 |            4 |            0 |
|      4 |    1 |   13 |            3 |            0 |
+--------+------+------+--------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you need to bracket your cases very clearly to show which ANDs and ORs go together - e.g. WHERE ((A AND B AND C) OR (D AND E)) AND F rather than WHERE A AND B AND C OR (D AND E) AND F

Comment: @mc110 Hmm... Thank you for your input. *finds another desk*

Comment: @LeeS i concure with mc110, your WHERE statement wont work as intended due to the use of OR MySQL will parse like this 

`WHERE mb.material_id = 2 AND mb.batch_status IN ( 'Arrived', 'Completed' ) AND mb.batch_type = 'whole' AND ( sti_id IS NULL OR (qty_recorded !=0 AND qty_expected !=0) ) AND st.status NOT IN ('Cancelled','In Progress')`

Without you specifying the Bracket's it will assume the condition's immediately left and right of the `OR` not all the condition's left and right of the `OR`

Comment: @MartinBarker Thank you for your input also. I'm canning this query for now I think and will come up with a slightly less efficient way of doing it because my brain is just not capable of writing one that works today!